# App released iAd banner not displaying ads

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

My application just got released on the App Store last Friday. Currently, there is a white banner at the bottom of the screen where ads are supposed to display. However, there are no ads shown at all. What's the problem?

iAd implementation:

```
func loadBanner() {
    adBanner = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    adBanner.center = CGPoint(x: adBanner.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height - adBanner.frame.size.height/2)
    adBanner.delegate = self
    adBanner.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(adBanner)
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    adBanner.hidden = false
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    adBanner.hidden = false
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Have you ran it in the simulator or on your device? If so what's the console coming back with?

Comment: Yes everything works perfectly.

Comment: Your talking about the home page ad right

Comment: yes its free and the ad banner is shown throughout the app

Comment: Can you post the code for the ad

Comment: I am having the same issue with GoogleMobileAds on both iOS and Android. It started early this week.

Comment: Are you using google ads or iAd or what

Comment: It takes a while for ads to populate at the beginning. You should have code to hide the ad (instead of showing a blank rectangle) when no ad is available.

Answer (score 1):

Once your application is approved for sale on the App Store it will also be reviewed by the iAd team before iAd advertisements are delivered to your application. This review can take up to 10 business days. If you are still not receiving advertisements after this time you should [contact Apple](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/44.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1) directly.

The reason you're seeing an empty white rectangle is because you are showing your `ADBannerView` when it actually fails to receive an ad here:

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    adBanner.hidden = false
}
```

You need to change this to hide the `ADBannerView` like so:

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    adBanner.hidden = true
}
```

Besides this, the rest of your implementation looks ok.

Comment: I think it´s a little cleaner when the banner stay hidden if error is not nil.

Comment: @MirkoBrunner No matter the error, if this delegate method is fired I'd suggest hiding the `ADBannerView` as something is more than likely not right. Printing the error wouldn't hurt, but its not necessary in answering this question.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. iÍ was to quickly with my comment.